# how to use text from title dynamic

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

Im using the following tool-tip code which I found in SO and currently the text is hard-coded in the title section, the problem is I need to use it in different label with different text title and not hard-coded to all the labels ,how should I change it to support any label with different title text.

```
 <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
                    <span class="label label-primary mytooltip">?</span>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
                </div>

        </div>
```

**This is the script**

```
 $(document).ready(    
        function () {

            $(".mytooltip").tooltip({
                animation: "true",
                placement: "right",
                title: "Tooltip texts....",
                trigger: "hover"
            });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have created a jsfiddle for you...

code:-

```
$(document).ready(    
        function () {

            $("[title]").tooltip({
                animation: "true",
                placement: "right",

                trigger: "hover"
            });
        });
```

hover on textbox and see the tooltip is working.you need to add a attribute **title** to the labels on which you want to show the tool tip.

working example:-http://jsfiddle.net/dwxmjkb3/10/

i have updated the jsfiddle for you, now if user will hover the label, input or ? then it will show the tooltip.i just added the title to the main div.

see the working example:-http://jsfiddle.net/dwxmjkb3/11/

thanks

Comment: Thanks but now just when I hover the text box I see the tooltip ,I want that when I hover the question mark also the tooltip will work...

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this:

```
$(".mytooltip").hover(function () {  // on hover event you want the tooltip with the right value.

        var tooltipText = $(this).val(); // set the value you want dynamically

        $(".mytooltip").tooltip({
            animation: "true",
            placement: "right",
            title: tooltipText,  // initialize the value of the tooltip
            trigger: "hover"
        });
   });
```

Comment: Thanks,how should I put the value in the span ?

Comment: by this: `title: tooltipText` - see in my answer