# Send tooltip title text dynamically

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I use text which is hardcoded in the title section,
the problem is I need to use it in diffrent label with diffrent text title and not hardcoded to all the labels ,how should I change it to support any label with diffrent titile text.

```
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.User, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.User)
                <span class="label label-primary tooltip">?</span>
            </div>

    </div>
```

JS

```
 function () {    
            $(".tooltip").tooltip({
                animation: "true",
                placement: "right",
                title: "My text",
                trigger: "hover"
            });
```

Comment: Need further clarification by what you mean by different label/different text.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to use text from title dynamic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25227431/how-to-use-text-from-title-dynamic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not sure if this is the right forum :) (I guess its related to JS),but anyhow you can
do it like following:

> 1.add title with the text
>
> 2.use this code:

```
$("[title]").tooltip({
    animation: "true",
    placement: "right",
    trigger: "hover"
});
```

In this case you take the text from the title.

Good luck!

Comment: Nice :) I will use it!Thanks!